# What is the proper syntax for the phoneme attribute in Android's TTS XML?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, ssml

My understanding is that this [X-SAMPA XML sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495301/best-practice-for-specifying-pronunciation-for-android-tts-engine/3647869#3647869), like other samples [here](http://groups.google.com/group/tts-for-android/browse_thread/thread/9a3defd28ccd18a7) and even [here](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/2.0/external/svox/pico/tests/data/xsampa_pico_man_en-GB.txt) & [here](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/2.0/external/svox/pico/tests/data/xsampa_pico_man_en-US.txt), is supposed to sound something.

```
String text = "<speak xml:lang=\"en-US\"> <phoneme alphabet=\"xsampa\" ph=\"faIv\"/>.</speak>";
mTts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

However, for some strange reason, it doesn't say anything (total silent).

What am I missing?

To clarify: My TTS sample app is setup OK: If I change that `.` before that `</speak>` tag to *any* word, the Android TTS just says that word fine. My only problem is that I am not able to utilize the `<phoneme alphabet=\"xsampa\" ph=\"faIv\"/>` in any way.

I understand that a `.` is supposed to be silent, but then according to the posters of those samples, it's supposed to sound the XSAMPA phonemes in the XML. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for what you are trying to do is exactly as you posted in your question. **If your phone is setup to use the default Pico TTS**, that is.

Under `Settings > Voice input & output > Text-to-speech settings > Default Engine` make sure that `Pico TTS` is selected and try the same code now.

Comment: Wow! That was it. This problem has been driving me crazy for a very long time without even suspecting that a different TTS engine might not support XSAMPA. Once I selected back Pico, the syntax above works as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for the [phoneme element](http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/#edef_phoneme) is documented in the W3C [Speech Synthesis Markup Language](http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/) documentation.

As mentioned in the answer Stack Overflow [question 3648239](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525424/does-android-tts-support-speech-synthesis-markup-language/3648239#3648239) not all elements are parsed properly.

There is further clarification of the parsing error in this [google groups forum post](http://groups.google.com/group/tts-for-android/browse_thread/thread/ee1940b9d0517d45?hl=en) however it would appear that these errors can be ignored.

You may be able to find more information in the [TTS-for-android site](http://groups.google.com/group/tts-for-android) on google groups by posting your question there.

I have been unable to read the samples as the website is down.  I'm not sure if this is a temporary problem ubt I will check back at a later date to see if I can find them.

Comment: Thanks +1 for the research. In my desperate search for a possible explanation I came across all the links you posted but that didn't help solve the mystery. See accepted answer above.