# Which SSML Tags are supported by Android TTS default engine

Tags: android, text-to-speech, ssml

I have searched a lot unable to find any solid solution for, which are valid ssml tags supported by Android TTS default engine. could any one please update me.

Will these tags support on all the android devices.

Comment: please refer this question's answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/3525424/4748639

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Android TTS support Speech Synthesis Markup Language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525424/does-android-tts-support-speech-synthesis-markup-language)