# How to audibly play IPA pronunciation on Android?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, ipa

I have the IPA pronunciation for a word which I would like to audibly play back to the user.

Can this be done using the built-in TTS engine? If not, is there a TTS engine out there that does support it?

Comment: Feature request here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55619

Comment: maybe x-sampa meets your needs: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495301/best-practice-for-specifying-pronunciation-for-android-tts-engine/3647869#3647869](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495301/best-practice-for-specifying-pronunciation-for-android-tts-engine/3647869#3647869)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As far as I know*, this cannot be done and there is no app that supports this.  The TTS engine supports only English, French, German, Italian, and Spanish (EFIGS).

Unless you have some linguistic knowledge, you are probably out of luck.  If you do, you could probably try to map the IPA to the most appropriate language (or maybe try Italian) and see how bad it is.

Answer (score 1):

Ivona supports this. They do have a free app for Android. It is a bit hard to setup, but perhaps this will get you going in a helpful direction.