# XSAMPA phonetic emphasis specification in Android

Tags: android, xml, text-to-speech

Thanks to [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/tts-for-android/7hlAudBRfUU/discussion) (referenced in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495301/best-practice-for-specifying-pronunciation-for-android-tts-engine) question) regarding the specification of phonetics, I'm able to use XSAMPA in the TTS engine. However, how am I to specify the [Primary Stress character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-SAMPA#Other_symbols) (double-quote, i.e. ") in the XML?

Sending XML like the following will end up not speaking anything, presumably because of the second (premature) occurrence of the double-quote character when specifying the ph= value:

```
"<speak xml:lang=\"en-US\"> <phoneme alphabet=\"xsampa\" ph=\"\"sE.v@n.ti \"wVn\"/>.</speak>"
```

Am I to just forget about the primary stress character because of the way the XML is specified, or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try `&quot;` as specified [here](http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html), instead of an intermediate `\"`?

So you would have:

```
"<speak xml:lang=\"en-US\"> <phoneme alphabet=\"xsampa\" ph=\"&quot;sE.v@n.ti &quot;wVn\"/>.</speak>"
```

Comment: I had tried &#34; but thought I wasn't doing something right, since it didn't make a perceivable difference, but it was just my test. Thanks!